# Checking user email calling Closio API in Rails - HTTParty and no method errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror, httparty, rails-api

I'm working with a team on checking a user's email input when they sign up for a web app.  The user will not be allowed to sign up if their email is not found with the following API call using HTTParty.  We are getting method_errors for whatever syntax is first within the function.  For, example, in the method below, "include" comes up as an undefined method error.

```
 def email_checker
            include HTTParty   
            default_params :output => 'json'
            format :json
            base_uri 'app.close.io'
            basic_auth 'insert_api_code_here', ' '
            response = HTTParty.get('/api/v1/contact/')

        @email_database = []
        response['data'].each do |x|
          x['emails'].each do |contact_info|
              @email_database << contact_info['email']
            end
            end

            unless @email_database.include? :email 
              errors.add :email, 'According to our records, your email has not been found!'
            end

  end
```

UPDATE:  So we went with the inline version of using HTTParty and our registrations controller (working with devise) looks like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

      def email_checker(email)
        YAML.load(File.read('config/environments/local_env.yml')).each {|k, v|  ENV[k.to_s] = v}
        api_options = {
          query: => {:output => 'json'},
          format: :json,
          base_uri: 'app.close.io',
          basic_auth: ENV["API_KEY"], ' '
      }

        response = HTTParty.get('/api/v1/contact/', api_options)
        @email_database = []
        response['data'].each do |x| 
          x['emails'].each do |contact_info|
              @email_database << contact_info['email']
            end
        end

        unless @email_database.include? email 
            return false
        else
            return true 
        end
      end


    def create
        super 
        if email_checker == false 
            direct_to 'users/sign_up'
            #and return to signup with errors
        else 
            User.save!
        end
    end
end
```

We're getting syntax error: "syntax error, unexpected =>"  Did we screw up the format?

Comment: This is in the user controller and we are also using Devise

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to use HTTParty, and you're trying to use both. Pick one :).

The class-based method would look something like this:

```
class CloseIo
  include HTTParty   
  default_params :output => 'json'
  format :json
  base_uri 'app.close.io'
  basic_auth 'insert_api_code_here', ' '
end

class UserController
  def email_checker
    response = CloseIo.get('/api/v1/contact/')
    # ... the rest of your stuff
  end
end
```

An inline version would look something like this

```
class UserController
  def email_checker
    api_options = {
      query: :output => 'json',
      format: :json,
      base_uri: 'app.close.io',
      basic_auth: 'insert_api_code_here'
    }
    response = HTTParty.get('/api/v1/contact/', api_options)
    # ... do stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  Ok we went with the inline version (btw, we're working with devise) please see edits above...